# Does response header get dropped after redirect?

Tags: rest, http, client-server, httpresponse

I am trying to send a JWT token from 1 api to another.

For testing purpose, I did this:

```
@GetMapping("somewhere")
public void handleRedriect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+"someRandomJWT");
        response.sendRedirect("https://www.quora.com/");    
}
```

When I observe the headers, "randomJWT" is present until 302 redirect request but gets omitted when "quora.com" is loaded.

[image: Before redirect]

**and after quora loads**

[image: Quora]

Answer (score 1):

Response headers are sent from the **server to the client** and that client is usually a browser like IE, FF, Chrome,Mobile Devices etc.. Headers only make sense if the receiving party can interpret it correctly. When you are sending a **response.sendRedirect** and also set some header like **Authorization**, the **browser will not forward** this header to the site it is now redirecting to.

If you are absolutely bent on passing some parameter to the site the browser will redirect to, you will have to **pass that parameter** as an URL parameter or you can generate altogether new identical request to be sent to your redirection server.

Comment: Thank. Could you elaborate on the last line i.e. new identical reques?
I guess right now it's getting auto generated by browser

Comment: A server wanting some data be sent along to the new URL should do so by appending it to the URL as querystring variables, for example: https://www.quora.com/?Authorization=someRandomJWT.

Comment: I understand the param appending part. Did you mean the same when you said generate new identical request?